# How can I make a square of implication arrows in mathmode?

Tags: math-mode

I have two equivalences

A <=> B

C <=> D

This poses no difficulty in math mode. However, how can I insert implication signs from A to C, and B to D (i.e. A => C, and B =>D) in a nice way?

Comment: This is something like a commutative diagramm and there are some packages for this, i.e. `tikzcd` etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use for example `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r,Leftrightarrow] \arrow[d,Rightarrow] & B \arrow[d,Rightarrow] \\
C \arrow[r,Leftrightarrow] & D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a version using an `array` and standard arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{c@{}c@{}c}
AAA & \implies & B \\
\Downarrow & & \Downarrow \\
D & \implies & D 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @student No problem. Consider upvoting any answer you find useful (both to your questions and those of others).

Comment: Sorry, Torbjorn, I have another question. What about if A and B are much longer expressions than C and D. How can I make the equivalence signs look the same? (with your solution, one equivalence sign is longer than the other)

Comment: @student I thought of one simple way of doing that, see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with [`xymatrix`](http://www.math.wichita.edu/~pparker/personal/latex/xyguide):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{
    A\ar@{<=>}[r] \ar@{=>}[d] & B\ar@{=>}[d]\\
    C\ar@{<=>}[r]             & D
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]